# The `attemptSilentLogin` from `express-openid-connect` library not working

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, oauth-2.0, express-openid-connect

I am using the `express-openid-connect` library. I'm trying to configure my app middleware like this:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const urlJoin = require('url-join');
const {
  auth,
  attemptSilentLogin,
  requiresAuth,
} = require('express-openid-connect');

async function middlewares() {
  const router = Router();

  router.use('/app1', auth(app1Config), attemptSilentLogin());
  router.use('/app2', auth(app2Config), attemptSilentLogin());
  router.get('/app1/login', requiresAuth(), (req, res) =>
    res.redirect(urlJoin(DOMAIN, '/v1'))
  );

  return router;
}
```

Flow/Steps:

- I go to `/app1` for the first time, and I am unauthenticated. I get a `skipSilentLogin` cookie created in the browser. (value: true, domain: DOMAIN, path: /app1)
- I go to `/app2` for the first time, and I am unauthenticated. I get a `skipSilentLogin` cookie created in the browser. (value: true, domain: DOMAIN, path: /app2)
- Then I go to `/app1/login`. I log in. I get redirected to `/app1`, as authenticated, and the `skipSilentLogin` cookie is gone.
- Then I go to `/app2`, and the `skipSilentLogin` cookie is still there. It didn't get deleted from here because the cookie has a different `path` = `/app2`, so log in from `/app1` didn't clear this cookie, and therefore the silent login is not attempted, and I am unauthenticated.

The idea is that I am logged-in in the first app, and when I go to the second one, I'm still logged in via the silent login.

What am I doing wrong? How can I configure this so the silent login works from `/app1` to `/app2`? Is there even a way to do it? Can the library do the silent login from different places (apps) under the same domain?